# Why Wildfly creates so much Artemis threads?

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

From the thread dump I can see that Wildfly created many `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.invmconnector` threads, like 200 or more and continues to increase this number. Many of them are 'parked' or were 'parked' at some point and now are just hanging there. After some time server runs out of memory.

What is the purpose of this thread, and why doesn't server delete them?

I am using `Widfly 14.0.1.Final` with an embedded `Artemis` broker.

Answer (score 1):

Well Wildfly needs to create Artemis server threads + client threads (for MDB, etc.)
InVMConnector is the client side of an in-vm connection.
I would recommend you to updgrade to WF20 and maybe use an external Artemis 2.13 broker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not possible at this moment...